# Flipping labels with a certain probability for the robustness test of a k nearest neighbour algorithm

Tags: python, probability, knn

I have a column 1D label vector, (200,) that has 2 classes (1,-1), the classes are randomly distributed in the vector (-1;1;1;-1;...;1)^T.

I would like to flip the labels with a probability of 20%. So the chance to flip the label from 1 to -1 is going to be 20% and vice versa.

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 import random

 n = len(labels)
 percent = 0.2

 partly_flipped = [ -1*labels[i] if i in random.sample(list(range(n)),int(percent*n)) else labels[i] for i in range(n) ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much it helped me